# Can't pass variable in wordpress wpdb->get_results

Tags: wpdb

I wanna pass a variable, but always get the error message

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...

Here is my code:

```
function second($taxonomies)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE manufacturer = $d", $taxonomies);
    foreach ($result as $pointer) {
    $id = $pointer->id;
    $car = $pointer->car;
    $price = $pointer->price;
    echo $id." ".$car." ".$price."<br />";
    }  
}
```

And how can I pass the result to another drop down?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in the Codex pages the [`get_results`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) doesn't provide the functionality to add a value parameter in the method:

```
$wpdb->get_results('query', output_type);
```

`output_type` has the following description:

> One of four pre-defined constants. Defaults to OBJECT. See SELECT a Row and its examples for more information.
>
> - OBJECT - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of row objects.
> - OBJECT_K - result will be output as an associative array of row objects, using first column's values as keys (duplicates will be discarded).
> - ARRAY_A - result will be output as an numerically indexed array of associative arrays, using column names as keys.
> - ARRAY_N - result will be output as a numerically indexed array of numerically indexed arrays.

You could use the following:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT *
     FROM tblTast
     WHERE manufacturer = %d
    ",
    $taxonomies
  )
);

if ( $results ) {
  foreach ( $results as $pointer ) {
    /* your code here */
  }
}
```

> We'll add the 'prepare' method to make sure we're not dealing with an illegal operation or any illegal characters

[See the Codex for more information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM tblTest WHERE manufacturer = %d",
        $taxonomies
    )
);
```

[See the codex on `wpdb::prepare()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks)

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like my variable is empty, cause I don'T get a result.

Comment: Here is my code to call the function. So why is my variable empty?

`<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
  <?php
   
   $taxonomies = 'Mustang';
   $select = second($taxonomies);
   echo $select;
  ?>
  <noscript><div><input type="submit" value="Go" /></div></noscript>
  </form>
`

What I also will do, but don't know how:
To read the taxonomy from my site and compare it with my database query, the results will be shown.